# How to center a drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a NavBar but whenever I have a dropdown I need to add I need to decide whether to put it right or left. Can anyone help me with a way to make it center.

I have tried to use the float element but it doesn't really do anything

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Products
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-doors-windows">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="pic-align" src="img/products/doors/doors_3.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="win-align" src="img/products/windows/windows_2.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
   .win-align {
      text-align: center;
      height: 250px;
      width: 190px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

  .dropdown-menu-doors-windows {
     width: 900px;
     height: 400px;
     border-top-right-radius: 15px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
     border-top-left-radius: 15px;
     opacity: 0.97;
   }

    .pic-align {
        text-align: center;
        height: 250px;
        width: 140px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see code. your parent element class {display: flex; justify-content: center}
floats don't work flex, bootstrap is built on flex